# Visualising frequency of events from time series

Tags: pandas

I have a series like this:

```
00:00:08,00:00:24,00:00:27,00:00:36,00:00:36,00:00:37,00:00:42,00:00:43,00:00:44,00:00:47,00:00:54,00:00:57,00:00:57,00:01:09,00:01:16,00:01:18,00:01:21,00:01:25,00:01:26,00:01:33,00:01:33,00:01:33,00:01:38,00:01:44,00:01:45,00:01:53,00:01:57,00:02:01,00:02:03,00:02:19,00:02:20,00:02:33,00:02:33,00:02:34,00:02:48,00:02:50,00:03:12,00:03:21,00:03:23,00:03:24,00:03:28,00:03:34,00:03:34,00:03:35,00:03:38,00:03:39,00:03:40,00:03:40,00:03:42,00:03:42,00:03:48,00:03:49,00:03:54,00:03:55,00:04:03,00:04:06,00:04:07,00:04:10,00:04:11,00:04:16,00:04:21,00:04:26,00:04:27,00:04:27,00:04:28,00:04:30,00:04:33,00:04:41,00:04:49,00:04:50,00:04:51,00:04:54,00:04:55,00:04:59,00:05:16,00:05:16,00:05:27,00:05:34,00:05:37,00:05:46,00:05:50,00:05:53,00:06:07,00:06:16,00:06:24,00:06:25,00:06:26,00:06:30,00:06:38,00:06:38,00:06:42,00:06:44,00:06:46,00:06:53,00:07:00,00:07:00
```

It is time in HH:MM:SS (as series in time dataframe)

I'm interested in finding / visualising amount of data points in (for example) 10 second window and plotting it as histogram barplot.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). This site is best used once you have a specific problem that you can't figure out around code that you are writing. Your question, instead, reads like "Can someone code this for me" or "Can someone point me towards a tutorial or information on how to code this" which are off-topic for Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Hi, so it is quite specific question, converting one thing to another, not a "make me an app" question.
I tried to find answer to this in google, but I could not find it.

Answer (score 0):

```py
# make it a list
time_series = "00:00:08,00:00:24,00:00:27,00:00:36,00:00:36,00:00:37,00:00:42,00:00:43,00:00:44,00:00:47,00:00:54,00:00:57,00:00:57,00:01:09,00:01:16,00:01:18,00:01:21,00:01:25,00:01:26,00:01:33,00:01:33,00:01:33,00:01:38,00:01:44,00:01:45,00:01:53,00:01:57,00:02:01,00:02:03,00:02:19,00:02:20,00:02:33,00:02:33,00:02:34,00:02:48,00:02:50,00:03:12,00:03:21,00:03:23,00:03:24,00:03:28,00:03:34,00:03:34,00:03:35,00:03:38,00:03:39,00:03:40,00:03:40,00:03:42,00:03:42,00:03:48,00:03:49,00:03:54,00:03:55,00:04:03,00:04:06,00:04:07,00:04:10,00:04:11,00:04:16,00:04:21,00:04:26,00:04:27,00:04:27,00:04:28,00:04:30,00:04:33,00:04:41,00:04:49,00:04:50,00:04:51,00:04:54,00:04:55,00:04:59,00:05:16,00:05:16,00:05:27,00:05:34,00:05:37,00:05:46,00:05:50,00:05:53,00:06:07,00:06:16,00:06:24,00:06:25,00:06:26,00:06:30,00:06:38,00:06:38,00:06:42,00:06:44,00:06:46,00:06:53,00:07:00,00:07:00"
time_series = time_series.split(',')


def histogram_from_time_series(_time_series):
    time_list = []

    for item in _time_series:
        t = item.split(":")
        try:
            time_list.append(datetime.datetime(year= 1970, month=1, day=1, hour=int(t[-3]), minute=int(t[-2]), second=int(t[-1]))) # has to be a datetime for it to work
        except IndexError:
            time_list.append(datetime.datetime(year= 1970, month=1, day=1, minute=int(t[-2]), second=int(t[-1])))

    _dict = {'Timestamp': time_list,} # make a dict from list
    _df = pd.DataFrame(_dict)   # make df from dict

    _df.insert(0, 'A', 1) # create a column and fill it with int(1)

    grouped = _df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Timestamp", axis=0, freq='30S')).sum() # group in given frequency and sum the 'A' 
    # https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases
    
    grouped.plot.bar(grid=True, figsize=(9,9)) # plot histogram

histogram_from_time_series(time_series)
```

[image: histogram]

Ok so I did it myself. Sharing if someone needs it later.